# Codeigniter load database; but check to see if database entry exists before attempting to load

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have code below which will load a database configuration group readonly if the database.php configuration file defines this.

The function works fine; but I don't really like including a file just to see if the entry exists in that file. Is there a cleaner way to get this function to work without doing an include; or is this the best method?

I have this static function in MY_Model.

```
public static function get_db_read()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    include APPPATH.'config/database.php';

    if (isset($db['readonly']))
    {
        $db_connector = $CI->load->database('readonly', TRUE);
    }
    else
    {
        $db_connector = $CI->db;
    }

    return $db_connector;
}
```

Comment: what is the higher level case where it wouldn't be set?

Comment: In production for my cloud solution I want to use a read replica; for my self hosted customers they wouldn't have a read replica. I want to dynamically act based on configuration of database.php

Comment: so you likley have either different environment variables or are autoloading slightly different config's that you could access without the include no? `if($this->config->item('self-hosted') )` ??

Comment: Right now configs are same (config.php).I guess I could set some variable in there ;but the only file I want my customer to modify is database.php for simple install. Right now I have that in .gitignore and config.php is setup in a way that they don't need to change between environments; I guess I could check the server URL also. I still lean towards the database method because it is easier to setup. Is there anything wrong with the way I am doing it? Is there a better way?

Comment: i don't see anything wrong. Some other thoughts though is check and see if `$db` isn't global and also not sure what `$this->load->database('unregistered-name')` returns.

Comment: $db is NOT global. It is loaded inside a function https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/fa91f30c144c041ad19925e55fe06c4065337896/system/database/DB.php#L63